# Override hover method in JUNG

Tags: java, jung

i am using the framework [vl-jung](https://github.com/timboudreau/vl-jung) to simulate a bubble GUI for directory browsing, now i am trying to override the hover method so that when i hover on a square it draws something else "add other nodes" i am using the [demo](https://github.com/timboudreau/vl-jung/tree/master/vl-jung-demo) in the library.

```
        public void hoverChanged(ObjectSceneEvent event, Object previousHoveredObject, Object newHoveredObject) {
        //System.out.println("hover" + Number);

        if (newHoveredObject instanceof Number) {
            hover = (Number) newHoveredObject;
            widget = findWidget(hover);
            task.schedule(750);
        } else {
            widget = null;
            hover = null;
            task.cancel();
            getSceneAnimator().animateForegroundColor(label, new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        }
    }
```

i tried adding the code of drawing the first time to the method but it's not working

```
    Factory<Integer> edgeFactory = new Factory<Integer>() {
    int i = 0;
    public Integer create() {
        return i++;
    }
};

Forest<String, Integer> createTree(Forest<String, Integer> graph) {

    //graph.addVertex("A0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "MyComp", "B0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "MyComp", "B1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "MyComp", "B2");
}
```

Comment: which class belongs this method `public void hoverChanged()` to?

Comment: the method belongs to SceneImpl.java

Comment: then when you create an instance of SceneImpl override the method like `new SceneImpl() { @Override public void hoverChanged()...};`